# How can we get value of nested for loop when create object in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

xyz.ts

```
let Lswiseprogress = currentStory.ls_wise_progress;
             for (let j = 0; j< Lswiseprogress.length; j++) {
                let lswiseprogressobj = Lswiseprogress[j];
                let lstitle = lswiseprogressobj.ls_title;
                let progress = lswiseprogressobj.progress;

                alert(lstitle);
                alert(progress);
             }

             let quizObj = {
                  subTopic: subTopic,
                  storyId: currentStoryId,
                  subject: subject,
                  concept: this.currentStory.concept,
                  state: this.currentStory.state,
                  button: this.currentStory.button,
                  startsOn: this.currentStory.startsOn,
                  endOn: this.currentStory.endOn,
                  lstitle: this.currentStory.lswiseprogress.lstitle,
                  progress: this.currentStory.lswiseprogress.progress,
                  quizObj: currentStory
               };

               this.storyDetails.push(quizObj);

           }
```

xyz.html

```
<ion-item class="bodyBgColor">
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            {{quizInfo.lstitle || "NA"}} :
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            {{quizInfo.progress || "NA"}} %
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-item>
```

I am new in ionic framework. Here, I am using nested loop one for currentStory which is an array and another for loop is lswiseprogress. After that I have create an object i.e. quizObj which consite the value of both array but in case of "lswiseprogress" value are not display but when I use alert inside the loop value are showing and How can I display lstitle and progress value ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: can anybody help me out please ?

Comment: What does it show? also where is the typescript code set? and when is it called?

Comment: if I am using quizObj inside the for loop I shows multiple data where I want to see list of lswiseprogress. it is called when I take login

Comment: I dont see `quizInfo` anywhere in TS code.. Please read [mcve]

Comment: see due to this quizInfo <ion-col width-45 class="col"  style="margin-right: 2.5%" *ngFor='let quizInfo of storyDetails'
                 [ngStyle]="{'height' : divheight|| 0}">

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add a [mcve]